# What's the necessity of Shemot 6:28?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, va-eira

[Shemot 6:28](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=88) says:

> "It was on the day that G-d spoke to Moses in the land of Egypt"

The previous verses describe family genealogy and the next verse is what G-d said. I looked at Rash"i and Ramba"n and I understand the explanation that the Torah is attaching this idea to what occurred many verses earlier that G-d spoke to Moses, and then the story was interrupted, and now this is a "reminder".

Regardless of that explanation, I don't understand why the Torah has to "remind" people of anything. I don't think this technique is used anywhere else. Besides, anyone reading the Torah, can of course, scroll a column to be "reminded".

Then, this seems like an unusual way to phrase a reminder. "It was on the day..." We would expect something **else** to have occurred. All this verse says, "it was on the day that G-d spoke..." and the next verse it says, again, that G-d spoke to them. If we, in fact, needed to be reminded of the story, doesn't verse 29 suffice as being that reminder?

Perhaps, verse 28 is needed for some other purpose than a reminder of the story or a "transitional" verse, but I don't quite see what that is.

Answer (score 1):

The translation and the Rashi on [Shmos 6:28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9867#showrashi=true) state that 28 and 29 are connected and would have been one verse in the English usage. The Torah uses the technique of summary elsewhere. For instance, the very beginning of Shmos repeats the names of the tribes even though we know this from the end of Sefer Breishis.

> 28 Now it came to pass on the day that the Lord spoke to Moses in the
>   land of Egypt,
>
> 29 that the Lord spoke to Moses, saying, "I am the Lord. Speak to
>   Pharaoh everything that I speak to you."
>
> **Rashi**
>
> **Now it came to pass on the day that the Lord spoke, etc.:** [This is] connected with the following verse: [“That the Lord spoke to
>   Moses”].
>
> **that the Lord spoke:** This is the very same speech stated above, “Come, speak to Pharaoh, the king of Egypt” (verse 11), but since
>   [Scripture] interrupted the topic in order to trace their [Moses’ and
>   Aaron’s] lineage, it returned to it [the statement, in order] to
>   resume with it